# Is it legal to divide with a variable

Tags: trigonometry

I know that I can't divide by $\cos x$ when solving an equation because it might be equal to $0$. In a worksheet, my teacher divided by $\cos x$. I want to know when can I divide by it.

$$\frac{8 \sin^2(x) (2\cos^3x-\cos x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{4\cos^5x+\cos x-4\cos^3x}{\cos(x)}$$

Comment: Not only this side is divided by cosx both sides @Patrick

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this post.  You can make the necessary edits.

Comment: @mazenghanem Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Here are two example that generalize easily.

1) Say I want to solve the equation $$x^2 = 2x.$$ Dividing by the variable $x$ yields $$x = 2.$$ But of course, $0^2 = 2(0)$. Because I divided by $x$ without first investigating what happens when $x=0$ I lost the data that 0 is a solution. The correct way to proceed if I really want to divide by $x$ would be to assert that I am considering $x \neq  0$ before dividing, and then consider the case $x = 0$ separately.

In light of the comment by vrugtehagel, I will include another example that may seem different. In fact, I teach pre calculus at a college and it does tend to confuse my students.

2) Suppose we want to solve $$3x = 2x.$$ I see right away that dividing by the variable might be a good idea, but of course, we cannot divide by 0, so first I inspect if 0 is or is not a solution. Evaluating at $x = 0$, I get 3(0) = 2(0), thus $0=0$ which is true so $x=0$ is a solution. Now I consider the same equation $3x = 2x$, but for $x \neq 0$. Since $x \neq 0$ it is permissible to divide by $x$, yielding $3 = 2$. This is the step where my pre-calc students tend to panic, because 3 is obviously not equal to 2, what does this mean!? There is no need to panic, this is still helping us solve our equation. One simply needs to know that the logical connective between elementary and legal algebraic manipulations is "if and only if". So what we have done is deduced that $$3x = 2x, \text{ for } x \neq 0 \text{ if and only if } 3=2.$$ Since the statement on the right is $\textit{always false}$, and since the connective is $\textit{if and only if}$ it means the statement on the left is $\textit{always false}$. Since $3x = 2x, x \neq 0$ is always false, we know that $3x \neq 2x$ for any $x$ other than 0. This means that the solution we found at the very beginning, $x = 0$, is the $\textit{only}$ solution, because that absurd conclusion of 3 = 2 that we got after dividing by $x$ means that no other real numbers can be solutions.

One also can probably easily see that in both of my examples, confusion can be avoided by factoring instead of dividing. E.g,

$$x^2 = 2x \implies x(x-2)= 0 \implies x = 0 \text{ or } x = 2,$$

$$2x = 3x \implies x(2-3) = 0 \implies x = 0.$$

But I solved my examples by dividing, since that was your specific question, to illustrate that it $\textit{is}$ ok to divide by the variable, as long as you know how to interpret the results of dividing by the variable.

Comment: Not only do you "lose" a solution, it can also just lead to things that are plain false; take $3x=2x$, then dividing by $x$ yields $3=2$.

Comment: This is really no different, and the falsity of the conclusion still answers the initial question of "for what real numbers $x$ is $3x = 2x$?",  but I see why it could seem different to someone learning. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Very nice elaboration! Indeed they are no different, but as you say, my example leading to an "impossible case" may confuse people (especially because the OP posed this question, it should be brought to light). +1

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is good to include. I suppose I could elaborate further and throw in the case when you divide by $x$ and end up with $1 = 1$. That throws my students off too, but hopefully OP now has enough to make sense of that situation, and all others, on their own :)

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by anything that is not constantly $0$ as long as you treat separately the case when that thing is $0$. That way, you obtain some solutions for $\cos{x}=0$ and some other solutions for $\cos{x}\neq 0$.

Comment: You can also divide by anything that is constantly $0$ as long as you treat separately the case that it is $0$.  It's just a little silly to do so.

Comment: That's why I dind't mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

We can divide for $\cos x$ but we have to consider  the extra condition $\cos x\neq 0$. We can then solve the new expression and find solutions from which we need to exclude that for which $\cos x =0$. Note that finally the solution for $\cos x=0$ must be checked on the original expression.

Note also that the same method applies for any expression $g(x)$ and if $g(x)\neq 0$ we don’t need extra conditions.